# Ajax in blogForm: Form being submitted more than once

Tags: ajax, 8

I'm currently building a Block Plugin for Drupal 8.
Within the `blockForm()` is an autocomplete field which additionally uses an AJAX callback after the autocomplete is finished.

In code it looks similar like this:

```
public function blockForm($form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  $form['field_foo'] = array(
    '#type' => 'entity_autocomplete',
    '#target_type' => 'node',
    '#ajax' => array(
      'callback' => array($this, 'fooAjaxCallback'),
      'event' => 'blur',
      'wrapper' => 'additional_fields'
    ),
  );

  $form['additional_fields'] = array(
    '#type' => 'fieldset',
    '#title' => t('Additional fields based on autocomplete'),
    '#prefix' => '<div id="additional_fields">',
    '#suffix' => '</div>'
  );

  return $form;
};

public function fooAjaxCallback($form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  return $form['settings']['additional_fields'];
};
```

What I want to achieve is to load additional form elements based on the autocomplete selection.

When using the autocomplete multiple times (searching for node one, changing to node two,..) the `#ajax` part is being fired each time the autocomplete changes (which is absolutely fine and a wanted behavior).

Submitting the block form after using the autocomplete multiple times leads to submitting it several times (exact: the amounts of #ajax runs from autocomplete field) but with different form states, only the last run will create a block with the changed values.

Any idea how to solve the problem?

Comment: Could be similar to this: https://www.drupal.org/node/2639180